# Pass data after clicking on button and navigating to another component (display this data in the other component )

Tags: typescript, vue.js, quasar

I'm about using post method in my user.vue  using vue js quasar typescript :

```
const onEditSubmit = async () => {
  try {
    

    const response = await axios.post('http://localhost/SPV2API/api/SalaryPackage/CreateSalaryPackage', data);
    const stepCreationList = response.data; // Assuming the response is an array of StepCreation objects
     console.log(stepCreationList,"setps");
    
    router.push({
      name: ROUTE_NAME.API_EXPLORER,
      
    });
  } catch (error) {
    
  }
};
```

This index.vue of my api-explorer :

```
    <template>
  <div class="q-pa-md">
    
    <q-stepper
      v-model="step"
      header-nav
      ref="stepper"
      color="primary"
      animated
    >
    
      <q-step
        :name="1"
        title="Total Salary"
        icon="settings"
        :done="done1"
      >
      <div> </div> </q-step> </div></template>
```

I want to display the result data in the

Comment: It seems like your question is cut off. Please edit it and add further information necessary to answer your question

Comment: @Goga for the stepper : it's in another .vue file , and the call of api is in another vue file I just want to call the post result index.vue file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to pass data from one Component to another. There are multiple ways to achieve that in `vue.js`, but the most straight forward in this case is passing the data as a `prop`.

```
router.push({ name: ROUTE_NAME.API_EXPLORER, props: stepCreationList });
```

In the Component where you want to use the prop, you can write:

```
defineProps<StepCreation[]>{}; // script setup syntax
```

More infos here: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#passing-props-to-route-components